# checking image width using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, file-upload, width

I have this bit of code here that I use to check for scenarios for my image gallery upload tool on my site. Currently I want to check for the size requirements, extension, and I also want to set a min width for the image, and if those don't meet my specifics I alert the user. I'm having trouble doing the min width for the image and can't find any real useful info on the internet to answer my question, can I check the images width with js?

```
jQuery.noConflict();
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
$('#fileupload').fileupload({
    dataType: 'json',
    add: function (e, data) {
        var goUpload = true;
        var uploadFile = data.files[0];
        if (!(/\.(gif|jpg|jpeg|tiff|png)$/gi).test(uploadFile.name)) {
            alert('You must select an image file only');
            goUpload = false;
        }
        if (uploadFile.size > 2000000) { // 2mb
            alert('Please upload a smaller image, max size is 2 MB');
            goUpload = false;
        }
        if (uploadFile.width() < 500) { // min width = 500px
            alert('Please upload an image with a width greater than 500 px');
            goUpload = false;
        }
        if (goUpload == true) {
            data.submit();
        }
    },
```

Comment: I saw that and tried clientWidth but it doesn't work! the image still gets uploaded.

Comment: Have you actually tried adding the uploaded image to the DOM per the question linked to by @humble.rumble then computing the width? Or did you just try `uploadFile.clientWidth`?

Comment: I tried how he did it in that question but it couldn't get it working.